# nuxt 2 build problems with emitted big

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, build, nuxt.js

npm run dev works perfect. When use npm run build it causes this problem. Build structure is wrong and when I try to test build by using http-server its approves that build is incorrect. In June build was working perfect and structure was same as in Cpanel.
I can show all code if someone need.
[error start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJriR.png)
[error end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGEJs.png)